# global Knex.raw is deprecated, use knex.raw (chain off an initialized knex object)

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.1, pg, knex.js

I am using `knex` and `pg` and I want to call a postgreSQL function from node.js preferably using knex.
i have used

```
const knex = require("knex");

exports.getAll = async (companyID) => {
  console.log("from here", companyID);
  const getAll = await databaseProvider
    .knex("attendance")
    .select(knex.raw("select * from get_allFromCompany('?')",[companyID]));
  return databaseProvider.executeQuery(getAll).then((result) => {
    return result.rows;
  });
```

But I am getting error:

```
global Knex.raw is deprecated, use knex.raw (chain off an initialized knex object)
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to acquire a connection
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:340:13)
    at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:264:8)
    at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:26:12)
    at Builder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:19:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
};
```

I have also tried several other hacks but I am unable to do so.
My sql query is

```
SELECT * FROM get_allFromCompany('1');
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize knex instance with dialect are you using and then create a query with bindings with knex and only after that you can use DB driver to execute it.

```
const knex = require("knex")({client: 'pg'});

exports.getAll = async (companyID) => {
  console.log("from here", companyID);
  
  const getAllQuery = databaseProvider
    .knex("attendance")
    .select(knex.raw("select * from get_allFromCompany('?')",[companyID])).toSQL().toNative();

  return databaseProvider.executeQuery(getAllQuery .sql, getAllQuery .bindings).then((result) => {
    return result.rows;
  });
```